# Detect presence of generator expressions in CMake

Tags: cmake

The use case for the following problem is macro packages which are deployed, so the input is entirely user defined.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
function(foo)
    cmake_parse_arguments(FOO "" "POSSIBLY_RELATIVE_POSSIBLY_GENEX_PATH" "" ${ARGN})
    # Chosen as an example for a necessary step which doesn't have a generator expression equivalent
    get_filename_component(
        ABSOLUTE_PATH
        "${FOO_POSSIBLY_RELATIVE_POSSIBLY_GENEX_PATH}"
        REALPATH
        BASE_DIR
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    )
    # Compatible with generator expressions by itself
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT
            ${MY_OUTPUT}
        COMMAND
            ${MY_TOOL}
            ${ABSOLUTE_PATH}
    )
endfunction()
```

`add_custom_command` itself supports  generator expressions, but the need to go via `get_filename_component` to handle one class of input (relative paths, for brevity in calling code), and the use of that intermediate step being impossible for the other class of input (build type dependent generator expressions, which get scrambled by `get_filename_component`) clashes.

`get_filename_component` effectively can't be used whenever `POSSIBLY_RELATIVE_POSSIBLY_GENEX_PATH` had contained any genex components. `get_filename_component` has no generator expression equivalent either, so substitution of that logic isn't possible.

Is there a robust way to detect the presence of valid generator expressions in a CMake variable, so it can be used as a signal *not* to attempt any non-genex transformations on that input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use command [string(GENEX_STRIP)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#genex-strip) which strips generator expressions from the string, and compare its result with original string:

```
string(GENEX_STRIP "${FOO_POSSIBLY_RELATIVE_POSSIBLY_GENEX_PATH}" no_genex)
if(FOO_POSSIBLY_RELATIVE_POSSIBLY_GENEX_PATH STREQUAL no_genex)
  # The string doesn't contain generator expressions.
  # It is safe to use e.g. 'get_filename_component'
else()
  # The string contains generator expressions.
  # This case requires special handling.
endif()
```